# Implement Push Notifications from Java Backend to Angular 4 Web App

Tags: angular, html, jakarta-ee, push-notification, web-push

I have a Web App which is developed in Angular 4 with Java Web Services for data transferring with server I need to implement Push Notifications in my web App which I have to send from my Java Back-end from Web Services code.
Please suggest me a good option to implement this and done my task.

Comment: checkout websockets implementation...

Comment: @kamlesh, did you figure this out ?